# Publish a Dynamics CRM Theme programatically?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-365

Is it possible to publish a Dynamics CRM Theme programatically ?  I've tried setting the "isdefaulttheme" flag to true but this causes an exception.

I can't see an SDK message to do it - but it can be done from the CRM UI so there must be a way somehow :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the PublishThemeRequest.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.publishthemerequest?view=dynamics-general-ce-9

```
PublishThemeRequest request = new PublishThemeRequest();
request.Target = new EntityReference(Theme.EntityLogicalName, defTheme.Id);
service.Execute(request);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ben's answer is perfect.  You can also do the same using WebAPI if you need to:

```
POST /CRMORG/api/data/v8.2/themes(11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111)/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.PublishTheme()
```